# Adding values to MySQL results array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, array-push

I'm using this to get MySQL results into an array

```
$var = array();
$sql = "SELECT doc as document ,part, `desc`, price, qty, total FROM parts LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {        
$var[] = $obj;  
}
```

That works great. Is it possible to add a value to each row? Something like

```
$var = array();
$sql = "SELECT doc as document ,part, `desc`, price, qty, total FROM parts LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {        
$var[] = $obj;  
array_push($var['url'] = $url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append url into $obj and then store $obj into $var array:

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {  
  $obj->url = $url;     // first store url into obj
  $var[] = $obj;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks - But I get 

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

on this line 

     $obj['url'] = 'ggggg';

Comment: Yes! Perfect. Thank you very much

Comment: @JayeshChitroda: if `$obj->url = $url;` works instead of `$obj['url'] =  $url;` please update the same in the answer. It can helpful for those who looking the same answer in future, it may possible that they miss your comments and simply check your answer only.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {        
    $var[] = array($obj,'url'=>$url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - But this puts the url outside of the row data - 

{{"document":"IH767898","part":"EHA320","desc":" 1.4 HH 11\/2","price":"10.31","qty":"1","total":"10.31","corder":"Frank"},"url":"www.test.com"}